# How to combine and create a list with certain criteria to a nested list in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, nested, counter

I had two list:

```
a = [0,0,2,2,2,2]
b = [1,3,2,3,6,7]
```

A and b correlated to each other, `a[i]` related to `b[i]` and I want to get

```
c = [[0,1,3],[2,2,3],[2,6,7]]
```

When `a` = `0`, there are 2 value in `b` that related to `0` which is `b[0],b[1]`, so connected them as the first inner-list of `c`,

When `a`=`2`, there are 4 value that related to `2` which is ,`b[2],b[3],b[4],b[5]`, but the gap between `b[3]` and `b[4]` is greater than `3`, so `c[2]` stop as `[2,2,3]` and create a new list that connected `a == 2` and `b[3],b[4],b[5]`

So my criteria is when `b[i],b[i+1]....` both related to a specific value of `a` but they have a gap which is `>= 3`, create a list `[a[i],b[i]]` first and then combine the others. I got stuck by it.

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating the groups according to `a`:

```
c = zip(a, b)

c = {k: [bi for ai, bi in g] for k, g in groupby(c, lambda i: i[0])}
```

Now concatenate to a list of lists (in order):

```
c = [v for k, v in sorted(c.items())]
```

Now you need a function to split by value gap:

```
def split_max_gap(l, max_gap=2):
    acc = [l[0]]
    for x, y in zip(l, l[1:]):
        if abs(x - y) > max_gap:
            yield acc
            acc = [y]
            continue
        acc.append(y)
    if acc:
        yield acc
```

Apply the splitting to the previous list of lists:

```
c = map(split_max_gap, c)
```

Flatten:

```
c = list(chain.from_iterable(c))
```

`c` should now hold:

```
[[1, 3], [2, 3], [6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

> the gap between b[3] and b[4] is greater than 3

but it is not greater. It is grater or equal.

```
a = [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2]
b = [1, 3, 2, 3, 6, 7]
c = []

for s in set(a):
    i = a.index(s)
    count = a.count(s)
    pom = []

    for j in range(i, i + count):
        if not pom:
            pom.append(b[j])
        elif abs(pom[-1] - b[j]) < 3:
                pom.append(b[j])
                if j + 1 == count:
                    pom.insert(0, s)
                    c.append(pom)
                    pom = []
                else:
                    pom.insert(0, s)
                    c.append(pom)
                    pom = [b[j]]

print(c)
```